# How to find the value of a variable that satisfies a function?

Tags: excel, matlab, solver, inverse

I have a function around 300 lines that takes in the friction coefficient (variable **u**) and a lot more constant parameters and outputs a Load (variable **P**). We could say P is somehow a function of u. This code is already finished. What I need now is to figure out a inverse method to calculate **u** that gives a defined value of **P**. Lets say i need **P to be 10**, what would be the friction coefficient **u** that satisfies this condition?

I could do that easily in Excel solver, but I'm struggling with MATLAB. I did some research and I figure that this is not a case where I want to minimize or maximize P, I want it to be a known value, thus I'm unsure of the uses of MATLAB functions for optimization.

I have tried to use a while over my entire code and testing various values of `u`, while `P` isn't inside the range I want (example, `u=0.01`, while `P` isn't `P>9.5 && P<10.5`, run my code, at the end `u=u+0.01`).

This is time consuming and it is not working properly.

Do you see a better way to do this?

Comment: Calculate f(u) for a wide range of u then interpolate to find u such that f(u)=P

Comment: trying to implement that, many thanks.

Comment: this helped alot since now i can see P variation with differents u. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find u such that P(u)=k for some constant k, you can minimize |P(u)-k|. you will get u so that |P(u)-k| is as close as possible, meaning P(u) is as close to k as possible. This can be done with matlab tools.

Another method you can use if P(u) is a polynomial is to find roots for P(u)-k. This can also be done with matlab.

And yet another option is as suggested in the comment, sample some values of u in a range, calculate P(u) for those values, and assuming there is a value in the range so that P(u)=k, you can use interpolation to estimate it. The interpolation can be done using matlab.

Comment: I still need to work little bit more on your answer, will do that later, but thanks for the insight....i can add at the end of my main code one last line P=P-10, and then minimize that.